# critics all be like

Tags: discourse-markers

*after last season critics all be like, "oh please please give us more complexity" since the end felt like i let down when the complex stuff end up being a red herring.*

Source: http://www.vox.com/2015/7/27/9045233/true-detective-recap-episode-6/in/8586222

Is the form "all be like" allowable in terms of standard grammar or is this some kind of informal way of written English?

Comment: The phrase *be like* is internet slang. It is often used in memes and funny video's, but it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @Sander *Be like* is not specifically internet slang: part of it is ordinary colloquial AmE and part is AAVE, which is increasingly used by younger speakers, often ironically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> after last season critics all **be like**, "oh please please give us more complexity" since the end felt like i let down when the complex stuff end up being a red herring. Now ya’ll get what you ask for and it ends up going over everyone’s heads and ya’ll demand simplicity lol.

There are two different colloquialisms in play here, **neither of which should be used in Standard English** (whatever that is).

- ***like*** (*I'm quoting an earlier post of mine on [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/9287/1597)*)

  *BE like* [with capitalized 'BE' indicating any form of the verb] is not an integrated collocation meaning *SAY*. Rather, *like* is a “discourse marker” which signals that what follows is worthy of particular emphasis or peculiar interpretation.

  > John was [like [totally excited about it]].
  >   John was [like [jumping up and down]].
  >   John was [like [“I’ll come”]].

  In the ‘quotative’ version, *like* indicates that what follows is an imitation or demonstration of what John ‘was’.
- ***be***
  The use of *be* as a finite verb equivalent to *am, are, is* is a dialect form. I believe it is current in a number of British dialects. In the US it is mostly  confined to Afro-American Vernacular English (AAVE); but the currently hip use a lot of AAVE, often ironically.

A paraphrase in Standard English might look like this:

> After last season you critics all said, "Oh, please, please give us more complexity" since the end, when the complex stuff ended up being a red herring, felt like it let you down. This year you got what you asked for, and it ended up going over everyone’s head, so now you demand simplicity. I am vastly amused.

Comment: I also think it would be more natural to say "all of you critics", instead of "you critics all"

Comment: @TBridges42 You may be right. I imported *you* into that opening to lend a possibly irrelevant consistency with the following sentence, addressed to  *y'all* (there spelt ‹ya'll›).  *You* may not belong there at all. Moreover, I'm not at all confident that *all* belongs to *critics* in the first place; it may belong to *be*, with the sense "completely, excessively*. So I left it in its original place after critics.

Comment: +1 How does this not have more upvotes. It's worth 20 just for the paraphrase.:) I was vastly amused.:)