# So I was all like "Huh? A conjunction?!"

Tags: idioms, adverbs, conjunctions

In idiomatic phrases like **I was/am all like "woah!"**, what is the usage of **all**? Is it an adverb, modifying the verb *to be*, or is it a quantifier modifying the <s>interjection</s> <s>conjunction</s> word *like*?

Corollary: In the example, is **like** an interjection, is it used in its adjectival sense as expressing resemblance, or is it really (as Dictionary.com claims) a conjunction?

Moon Unit wants to know.

Comment: She could have asked Maynard G. Krebs.

Comment: To me, the word "like" indicates that a emotion/attitude/behavior will be presented in a direct quote form but is not necessarily a direct quote. I was was going to post an something but I saw StoneyB's answer and I was all like "f- this I can't top this guy". Also, I don't feel that there is much difference between "like" and "all like" in this particular idiomatic phrase.

Comment: @Leo ... and **all like** implies that the described speaker is _acting_ in a certain way/ This is why it constantly occurs to me that *all* modifies **like** in this idiom. So it's not just like, but _all_ like. StoneyB says it's an adverb, though, and his reasoning and explanation are clear. Still...

Comment: "A pluperfect fink". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlVcrsjHPbg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is an extension of an earlier answer on this topic [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/63147/32).*

I take *all* here to be an adverb meaning "completely" or (in some contexts) "excessively".

There's a substantial literature on the "quotative" construction *be like*. [Here](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/29/paper2690.pdf)'s a sample paper, with a bibliography; I hasten to confess that I haven't read most of these. My own reading of the idiom takes *be like* to be a little bit more than just a quotative, a construction for introducing quoted speech.

- First, *like* has been at least since I was a boy in the 1950s a common colloquial [*discourse marker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker) in the US, signalling that what follows is worthy of particular emphasis or peculiar interpretation.
- Second, the *be* here is not the ordinary copular *be*, but 'behavioral' *be*, the *be* used in the progressive construction to mean *behave*:

  > COPULAR: John is a jerk ... *Jerkhood is attributed to John as a permanent quality, what some linguists call an 'individual-level predicate'.*
  >
  > BEHAVIORAL: John is being a jerk ... *= 'John is behaving like a jerk'; jerkhood is attributed to John as a temporary quality, a 'stage-level predicate'.*
- Third, *be like* is not restricted to introducing quoted speech: it may also introduce reproduced *behavior*. The "quotation" may be non-linguistic, composed of gestures and non-linguistic sounds, and if it has a linguistic component this is accompanied by a (usually exaggerated) performance of the words and intonation.

My reading is that in this idiom two common uses of *like*, as a discourse marker and as a comparator, have merged and have combined with behavioral *be* to introduce not just a quotation but a **performance**—a demonstration of the subject's behavior.

Comment: at the risk of forcing you to do more work: what becomes of **all**, then? Adverb? Quantifier of "like?"

Comment: ¡WORK!  <--Krebsian inflection indicated

Comment: @P.E.Dant It's right there at the top: adverb meaning "completely, excessively". And my goodness it's nice to find somebody else who remembers Dobie Gillis!

Comment: I have copies of every extant episode. As a lad, Thalia Menninger was the girl of my dreams. So it's an adverb after all.

Comment: Actually, Thalia would not have made much of lad. _When I was a lad, Thalia Menninger was the girl of my dreams._

Comment: I feel like *all*, in this sort of slang usage, doesn't really mean "completely" or "excessively".  [Idiomatically, it just kind of means "said" or "reacted"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20was%20all), although maybe there is a connotation that it's a strong reaction or that it characterizes the speaker at the moment.  I can't imagine someone using it for a purely factual statement, like "He asked where the post office was, and I was all like 'It's on Third Street.'"